# How to count the number of images in td in table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in html ,containing 5 rows , and each row , has 3 td, the second td for each row has a random number of images , I want to count the number of images that created in that td .
in my code ,  I get a random number and make a loop to create number of pictures in td that has an id ="one" and so on 
but I need a function to count the number of images to compare it with the user answer , when the user write the number of the children in the third td , and press enter , I want to compare his answer with the real number of children in the second td 
[image]

in JS

```
function newProblem(){

document.getElementById("one").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("two").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("three").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("four").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("five").innerHTML="";

var y= getRandomNum();


    while(y>0){
         var x= document.getElementById("one");


         var img = document.createElement('img');
         img.src = "images11.jpg";
         x.appendChild(img);

         y--;

        }
        var z= getRandomNum();


         while(z>0){
         var x= document.getElementById("two");


         var img = document.createElement('img');
         img.src = "images11.jpg";
         x.appendChild(img);

        z--;

        }
        var a= getRandomNum();

        while(a>0){
         var x= document.getElementById("three");


            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = "images11.jpg";
            x.appendChild(img);

            a--;

        }
        var b= getRandomNum();


        while(b>0){
         var x= document.getElementById("four");


         var img = document.createElement('img');
         img.src = "images11.jpg";
         x.appendChild(img);

        b--;

        }
        var c= getRandomNum();


         while(c>0){
         var x= document.getElementById("five");


         var img = document.createElement('img');
         img.src = "images11.jpg";
         x.appendChild(img);

        c--;

        }
                   //function to get random number

              function getRandomNum(){

             var min = 1;
            var max = 13;
            return  RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)


             }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for that :

```
var count = document.querySelectorAll('td img').length
```

If you want to count images in one `td`, you can use the `id` of the `td` :

```
var count = document.querySelectorAll('#one img').length;
```

Comment: is it useful for each td?

Comment: thank you @magus , but i didn't use jquery  never , how i could put this in my js code

Answer (score 1):

In plain js you can do this:

```
var cnt = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('img').length
```